# Why executive (exe) converted from python (py) doesn't work properly on other computers?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I made this program (Youtube Playlist Downloader, both video and MP3 formats), it works perfectly on my computer, but when I transfer it to another computer only the video works but is unable to download MP3, as mp3 uses ffmpeg that is already installed on my machine but not installed on other machines. However, isn't pyinstaller responsible for including everything that the program uses when converting it to exe so that it works on other machines?

I also installed pytube manually just like ffmpeg (which means there is no pytube on other normal computes unless you manually install it, but the weird thing was the program was able to download video playlist, only unable to download the mp3 part which needs ffmpeg) ..

Is there any other good way to convert?

Comment: I suspect your problem is: pyinstall includes all *python* dependencies. It does not include random other binaries that are spawned as subprocesses.

Comment: I see!, then how am I going to fix this?

Comment: Can you create python code to download and install ffmpeg?

Comment: I think I can do that

Comment: Presumably, link to the FFMPEG *libraries* rather than shelling out to them? I admit to not being particularly familiar with pyinstaller, since I'm used to working on Linux where it's easy to install things. This will likely be a fair amount of work if the current python libraries have to be redesigned to use the C libraries, but once working it should be reliable. You should get used to the CFFI documentation at least.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely take that into consideration. :))

Comment: python wasn't created to built exe files and tools like `pyinstaller` still have problem to find all Python modules and C/C++ libraries needed to run it. You would run exe in console to see all errors and it may show what it can't find - and later you can use special file `.spec` to add this module/library and create again exe. You can find more in pyinstaller documentation